# Deploy a WSP solution from one farm to another

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, solution-package, sub-site, farm

I have a WSP solution which is a subsite with all its content which I want to install on another farm. What are the implications? Is it possible, if so, is it advisable?

Comment: add SharePoint version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have wsp file then you can install it to other farm (I am assuming 2nd farm is also on same sharepoint version).

Also make sure you follow the same deployment steps as you did in your 1st farm.

1 thing, I noticed sometime developer use the hard coded URL in the code...so u have to make sure no hard coded URL in ur wsp.

Comment: so I cannot deploy say from SP 2013 vs to SP 2016 version?

Comment: You Cannot deploy it cross version.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fba2a122-c1cd-4685-812b-c1cf2875f0fa/farm-solution-deployment-in-sharepoint-2016?forum=SP2016) by @Trevor Seward, you'll be able to deploy the WSP in SP2016 as you deploy in SP2013 in most cases.

But please keep in mind the [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208899/deploy-a-wsp-solution-from-one-farm-to-another/208901#208901) given by @Waqas Sarwar MVP.

[New and improved features in SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346121%28v=office.16%29.aspx) will help you to learn more about SharePoint 2016 features.

Answer (score 0):

WSP's are reusable solution packages and there won't be any problems. but make sure you are deploying in the same SharePoint version farm say 2010, 2013 or 2016.